# Inserting a Banner Image on Top of Every Page CSS

Tags: html, css

I am learning how to create a website and I have stumbled upon a problem I can't figure out. I want to place a banner on the top of every webpage page of the site, and I was wondering if this can be done using a .CSS. I have a background already on the .CSS but I can't seem to insert a picture properly on top. This is my code:

```
 hr {color:sienna;}
 p {margin-left:20px;}
 body {
 background-image:url("pic2.png");
 }
```

And then I would call it on every page like (the css file name is style.css):

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Comment: Is the path to your image correct?

Comment: check to make sure it's not "*~/Images/pic.png*". If you're storing pictures in a separate folder.

Comment: @NicholasV. The "pic2.png" is not the banner i want to put, that is the background, which is displaying properly. The banner I want to insert at the top of every page is another image, which i do not know how to insert.

Comment: @j08691 Read statement above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Like this...?

#### JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/Yd4d6/

```
<div id="banner"></div>
<div id="content">
    Hello world
</div>
```

```
#banner {
    background:url('http://sweetclipart.com/multisite/sweetclipart/files/imagecache/middle/banner_white.png');
    width:100%;
    min-height:189px;
}
```

**Or do you want it to dynamically apply the element to your page?**

---

**For further insight, we need more data:**

- Will your **banner** be static, that is, always the same size and same place?
- Will this show up on EVERY page, and do you want it just PLACED into the DOM?

If you are trying to actually **add elements** to your page, **CSS** only allows to perform `pseudo operations` with existing elements on your page.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/fPU9Sdc.png I have attached that image that maybe clarifies what I am asking for. I already have a background that is working correctly (pic2) which is represented in black. Now I want to add a small banner on top of EVERY page and call the .css file from every page. I was wondering if this could be done using .css since I cannot find anything about it.

Comment: CSS will not auto generate it, but I can give you an easy solution if you are able to add an item to every page, append an element to every page's html, be it PHP, JS, or whatever.

Comment: Yeah that was what I was doing, but I was wondering if it could be done via CSS because lets say for example i have a huge website with 100 pages and I want to change the banner every 4 months. I would have to open all 100 files and change manually. So i wanted to know if there was a way around that. Guess not. Thanks!

Comment: You absolutely can easily! You would have to have `<div id="banner"></div>` in all your pages. Then you could change one `css` file with the **BG Image**

Comment: Oh yes that worked! I think i was misunderstanding you because you said something about putting a code on top of every page and i immediately thought that you were referring to putting the img location on every page. But now i understand, thanks!

Comment: No problem :-) Thank you for the accepted answer. And you DO need code on top of every page, but its **HTML** and very simple. `<div id="banner"></div>`

Comment: When I click on this [link](https://mobilemonkey.com/case-studies/mobilemonkey) I will see that after a couple of seconds a narrow strip/bar will appear at the bottom of the page. I have a website built with `Nunjucks` template (`html`, `javascript`, etc) that I would like to place a simple unobtrusive banner (narrow strip) on its homepage, to appear after a few second, where I can provide a little text or link or invitation to a survey. Is the answer to this post how I should do it, or is what I am looking for a totally different thing?

Answer (score 1):

I found one syntax error in you codes.

you can use only either use

```
background-image:url("pic2.png");
background-repeat:repeat;
```

or

```
background:url("pic2.png") repeat;
```

Comment: @JoshC ok its not syntax, can i say logical mistake or something else